# What shell script is calling rsync?

Tags: rsync, shell

For the last couple of days, I've woken up to find rsync churning away with 1.6GB of memory, slowing my Mac down significantly. Activity Monitor only says that rsync is coming from sh, but I'm trying to track down more info; specifically, what shell script is calling rsync. How can I find that out?

Comment: I blame the Mayans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple. Use the ps command to check the parent of the rsync process, something like this.

Use this command

# ps -ef | grep rsync

This will give you the process ID of the rsync script. This will also give the process id of the parent script which is running that rsync process.

Then use this command

# ps -ef | grep parent_process_id

This will tell you the name of the script which is running the rsync script.

Hope this helped.